# TCL regex match only full words in a list

Tags: regex, tcl

i am working with the regexp command in TCL to get the amount of times, some string occurs in a list. So i have created following example:

```
set text "Gi Gi Gi Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Twe Twe Gi Gi Te Te Te Te"
set things2searchfor "Gi Te Tw Twe"

foreach entry $things2searchfor {
    set allregexmatches [regexp -all -inline $entry $text]
    set numbrofmatches [llength $allregexmatches]
    puts "There are $numbrofmatches matches found for $entry and they all are: $allregexmatches"
}
```

When i run the script it gets me following output:

```
There are 5 matches found for Gi and they all are: Gi Gi Gi Gi Gi
There are 4 matches found for Te and they all are: Te Te Te Te
There are 12 matches found for Tw and they all are: Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw
There are 2 matches found for Twe and they all are: Twe Twe
```

So the problem i have is, that I only have 10 Tw entries in the original list, but the regex matches the two Twe as well and causes the match count to get to 12.

So most of the regex solutions point me to use the dollar sign to mark an end of a line. This causes to only match the last Te because it is on the end of the line. Other solutions are to do not match XYZ, but as i am working with variables, i cant categorically not match for xyz as the input is different on every foreach and entirely different on every network device. I tried to work with the word boundry /b but this does not work either.

Any other solutions to match only full words and not parts of it? I cannot use the lsearch command as i am using TCL 8.3 here... (Thanks Cisco)

Comment: 8.3? That's not been supported for... well, it was on long term support two decades ago, but that lapsed after 8.5 came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar strategy to @Mkn but count everything into a dict.

```
foreach item $text {
    dict incr counts $item
}
foreach item $things2searchfor {
    puts "$item\t[dict get $counts $item]"
}
```

```
Gi  5
Te  4
Tw  10
Twe 2
```

---

An older Tcl? Use an [array](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl22.html) instead

```
array set counts {}
foreach item $text {
    if {[info exists counts($item)]} {
       incr counts($item)
    } else {
       set counts($item) 1
    }
}
parray counts
puts "==="
foreach item $things2searchfor {
    if {[info exists counts($item)]} {
        puts "$item\t$counts($item)"
    }
}
```

```
counts(Gi)  = 5
counts(Te)  = 4
counts(Tw)  = 10
counts(Twe) = 2
===
Gi  5
Te  4
Tw  10
Twe 2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Although this solution uses the dynamically created list things2searchfor and can therefore be used on all devices, the problem is that TCL 8.3 does not support the dict command. Saldy Cisco only supports 8.3 which is back from 2002. Hopefully, your solution might help somone else that stumbles unto this post in the future.

Comment: It says: can't read "counts(Gi)": no such element in array
    (reading value of variable to increment)
    invoked from within
"incr counts($item)"
Not sure if this is a limitation of TCL 8.3 or maybe there is an error in the code. I havent worked with arrays that much so im not sure if you are supposed to create the "key" whitin the arry first in order to be able to increment it.

Comment: I forgot that `incr` used to break if the variable was unset. Fixed.

Comment: Perfect. Although TCL 8.3 cant use parray. the rest of the script works great and the goal is achieved. Thank you very much for your contribution. I learned some new things today.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i just found the solution after reading the TCL Regex help page here:
https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/re_syntax.html#M30
Here it says:

> \M - matches only at the end of a word

I changed the Regex in TCL (escaping with an additional backspace) to this:

```
[regexp -all -inline "$entry\\M" $text]
```

And now it works as expected:

```
There are 5 matches found for Gi (searchpattern: Gi\M) and they all are: Gi Gi Gi Gi Gi
There are 4 matches found for Te (searchpattern: Te\M) and they all are: Te Te Te Te
There are 10 matches found for Tw (searchpattern: Tw\M) and they all are: Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw
There are 2 matches found for Twe (searchpattern: Twe\M) and they all are: Twe Twe
```

Sorry for posting before absolutely reading all the manuals. Thanks to anybody who may already have invested any resources to look for an anser.

Comment: I even added another expression to match at the start of the word too: [regexp -all -inline "\\m$entry\\M" $interfacenamelist], just to make sure a future name like UTe wont match all Te entries too, causing the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

A solution without `regexp`

```
set text "Gi Gi Gi Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Tw Twe Twe Gi Gi Te Te Te Te"    
foreach entry $text {
    switch -exact -- $entry {
        Gi  {incr Gi}
        Te  {incr Te}
        Tw  {incr Tw}
        Twe {incr Twe}
    }
}
```

No tested in 8.3

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Very elegant and simple solution. It works in 8.3, didnt know about the exact parameter in a switch. The only problem i see with this solution is, that the things2searchfor list is getting filled dynamically. So depending on the device, it will have more or less entries in it. Not sure how you could build a switch with dynamic entries...